# Getting error while assign a value to session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am developing an application in asp.net using c#. In my code segment I have to set a value to a session variable. When I am trying to assign a value to the session it gives me an error called "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I don't know why it is coming. The code is like following

```
Session["User_ID"]="shubhadeepchat@gmail.com";
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is the line where you get the error? Or some other line?

Comment: @Arbaaz In this line I am getting error.

Comment: @Arbaaz Problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Set
{
     public string setSession()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"] = "shubhadeepchat@gmail.com";
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

now in code behind create an instance of setSession.call the method setSession and see the output as shubhadeepchat@gmail.com.

try this code on page_load event

```
Set objset = new Set();
Response.Write(objset .setSession());
```